# Unit Testing HttpURLconnention

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am writing Unit Test for Method Which makes Http POST Request using HttpUrlConnection in java.I am using PowerMockito for mocking URL,Proxy.

```
@Before
   public void setUp()
   {
           impl=new httpClient();

   }
    @Test
    public void httpClientTest()
    {
        try {
            URL obj= PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
            Proxy proxy = PowerMockito.mock(Proxy.class);
            InetSocketAddress inetAddr=PowerMockito.mock(InetSocketAddress.class);
            HttpURLConnection mockConn = PowerMockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
            PowerMockito.whenNew(InetSocketAddress.class).withArguments(anyString(),anyInt()).thenReturn(inetAddr);
            PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments(any(String.class)).thenReturn(obj);
            PowerMockito.whenNew(Proxy.class).withArguments(Proxy.Type.HTTP,inetAddr).thenReturn(proxy);
            PowerMockito.when(obj.openConnection(proxy)).thenReturn(mockConn);
            JsonObject req=new JsonObject();
             String response=impl.makeRequest("abc",req);
             System.out.println(response);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }



    public void makeRequest(String empid,JsonObject request)
        {
            JsonObject variables=request.getJsonObject("variables");
            variables.put("requested_for",empid);
            request.put("variables",variables);
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            JsonObject successResponse;
            try
            {
                String url = "Some_valid_url";
                URL obj = new URL(url);
                 String proxyURL="abc.xyz.com";
                 int port=80;
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyURL, port));
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)obj.openConnection(proxy);
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
                System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation", "false");  //SSL certificate validation false
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                String requestBody= request.toString();
                wr.writeBytes(requestBody);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }


   }
```

I am getting this exception while running test.

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: type null is not compatible with address null 
    at java.net.Proxy.<init>(Proxy.java:95)
        at sun.net.ApplicationProxy.<init>(ApplicationProxy.java:37)
        at sun.net.ApplicationProxy.create(ApplicationProxy.java:41)
        at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1018)
```

exception is getting caught at
  PowerMockito.when(obj.openConnection(proxy)).thenReturn(mockConn); this point in  test.

Comment: But you're not injecting any mock in your code under test, you're using `new` so it will never use your created mocks

Comment: I would first want to check which mocks are not loaded or are not injected. For eg, JsonObject variables=request.getJsonObject("variables"); . Here your request is from a real object, but what is the expectation from this call?

Comment: Instead of mocking out the Proxy instance use 
   Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Type.HTTP, inetAddr);
That is still not the answer but one step ahead. Proxy is somehow immutable according to Javadoc and you need to initialize all the fields inside before the methods will act as intended. Instead you might want to create an instance.

Comment: Also found that URL is a final class that cannot be mocked out of the box you need some extra configuration to make it work. https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final

Answer (score 0):

Found that your code is missing two annotations and two more "when"s. By adding the two annotations **@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)** and **@PrepareForTest({URL.class})** the issue you noticed was fixed. This way the **final URL.class** was mocked as expected.

```
@RunWith(org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({java.net.URL.class})
public class UrlConnectionTest {

    private HttpClient impl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        impl = new HttpClient();
    }

    @Test
    public void httpClientTest() {
        try {
            URL obj = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
            Proxy proxy = PowerMockito.mock(Proxy.class);
            InetSocketAddress inetAddr = PowerMockito.mock(InetSocketAddress.class);
            HttpURLConnection mockConn = PowerMockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
            PowerMockito.whenNew(InetSocketAddress.class).withArguments(anyString(),anyInt()).thenReturn(inetAddr);
            PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments(any(String.class)).thenReturn(obj);
            PowerMockito.whenNew(Proxy.class).withArguments(Proxy.Type.HTTP,inetAddr).thenReturn(proxy);
            PowerMockito.when(obj.openConnection(proxy)).thenReturn(mockConn);
            PowerMockito.when(mockConn.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(System.out);
            InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("Hello world".getBytes());
            PowerMockito.when(mockConn.getInputStream()).thenReturn(myInputStream);
            String response = impl.makeRequest("abc");
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I executed the same test code but URL is not getting mocked.When i passed dummy url,it is giving malformedurl exception.